# convert curl xml response to json or array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, xml, curl

Good afternoon friends,

I need your knowledge, I have a curl php function which responds perfectly, but it has been a real headache for me to pass those results to a JSON or ARRAY, I have tried several ways without success,

the response i get from curl XML is this

```
0<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <mensaje> <version>2019.11.04</version> <nca-respuesta> <codigo-Error>0</codigo-Error> <texto-Error>Transaccion Exitosa</texto-Error> <transaccion> <boleta>2414</boleta> <tipo>1</tipo> <monto>24990</monto> <vendedor>111111</vendedor> <rutcp>1111111</rutcp> <numero-transaccion>2414</numero-transaccion> <folio-DTE>11111111</folio-DTE> <tipo-documento>2</tipo-documento> <fecha>04/11/2022</fecha> <sucursal>37</sucursal> <terminal>105</terminal> <factura-normal>0014122272 </factura-normal> <factura-moto> </factura-moto> <rut-emisor>111111</rut-emisor> </transaccion> <fidelizacion> <rut-bonificacion>111111</rut-bonificacion> </fidelizacion> <regalo> </regalo> <articulos> <articulo> <item>1</item> <upc>2000388411434</upc> <precio>16990</precio> <cantidad-comprada>1</cantidad-comprada> <rmc>2</rmc> <servicios> </servicios> <descuento> <tipo>1</tipo> <monto>4495</monto> </descuento> <cantidad-maxima-devolver>1</cantidad-maxima-devolver> <monto-maximo-devolver>9000000</monto-maximo-devolver> <rut-anfitrion>111111111</rut-anfitrion> </articulo> <articulo> <item>2</item> <upc>2000369667645</upc> <precio>16990</precio> <cantidad-comprada>1</cantidad-comprada> <rmc>2</rmc> <servicios> </servicios> <descuento> <tipo>1</tipo> <monto>4495</monto> </descuento> <cantidad-maxima-devolver>1</cantidad-maxima-devolver> <monto-maximo-devolver>9000000</monto-maximo-devolver> <rut-anfitrion>16665688</rut-anfitrion> </articulo> </articulos> <fpagos> <fpago> <tipo>4</tipo> <nombre>Tarjeta de Credito Bancaria</nombre> <marca>MA</marca> <tipo-tarjeta>C</tipo-tarjeta> <rut>14122272</rut> <numero-tarjeta>0</numero-tarjeta> <tipo-cuota>1</tipo-cuota> <numero-cuotas>1</numero-cuotas> <vencimiento>1111</vencimiento> <autorizacion>790425</autorizacion> <codigo-unico>111111111111111111</codigo-unico> <monto>24990</monto> <monto-devuelto>0</monto-devuelto> </fpago> </fpagos> <fpromocion> <id-cliente>111111111111</id-cliente> <tipo-id-cliente>1</tipo-id-cliente> <email-transaccion>cpruebas@pruebas.com</email-transaccion> </fpromocion> </nca-respuesta> </mensaje>
```

The other thing that I have tried is to pass that result to text to delete the line of text "0 " with $str but I have not had any success either,

I don't know what else to try, I leave you part of the function

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => '',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:SOAP-ENC='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' xmlns:xsi='' xmlns:xsd='' xmlns:ns2='' xmlns:ser='http://service/'>
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ser:NCAtomaticaDTE>
            <arg0>
                <![CDATA[
                    <mensaje/>
                        <nca-requerimiento>
                            <programa>
                                <version>Version VER6207I 23/01/2012 09:30</version>
                                <timeout>11</timeout>
                            </programa>
                            <datos-originales>
                                <fecha>$fecha_compra_boleta_formateada</fecha>
                                <sucursal>$sucursal_boleta</sucursal>
                                <terminal>$numero_terminal_boleta</terminal>
                                <numero-boleta>$numero_folio_boleta</numero-boleta>
                                <folio></folio>
                                <rmc></rmc>
                            </datos-originales>
                        </nca-requerimiento>
                    </mensaje>
                ]]>
            </arg0>
        </ser:NCAtomaticaDTE>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'SOAPaction: kkkk',
    'Content-Type: application/xml'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

echo $response;
```

```
I tried to pass the result to json or array with no success, I also tried to pass the result to text
```

Comment: A few questions: you say "I tried to pass the result" - what exactly did you try? Please add it to the question, not as a comment. Also, are you sure `$response` starts with `0` as in your question?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone it may help. I had the same issue; the returned XML is not valid. You need to verify it and see which lines need to be removed.

After displaying it in the browser, go to the "view page source" option, copy it, and use some online code validation tools. There, you can identify which lines need to be removed to make it a valid XML.

Afterward, I had to run it through "html_entity_decode" before being able to use "simplexml_load_string."

```
$xmlString          = curl_exec($curl);
$start              = strpos($xmlString, '&lt;?xml');
$end                = strpos($xmlString,'</a:XmlCfeSign');
$xmlString          = substr($xmlString, $start, $end-$start);
$xmlStringDecoded   = html_entity_decode($xmlString);
$xmlStr             = simplexml_load_string($xmlStringDecoded);

print($xmlStr->name);
```